# Is it possible to change your associated e-mail on Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I signed up for Pokemon Go with my school e-mail that will soon be deleted. Is there any possible way to change the e-mail I use to sign in without losing all my game progress?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the email associated with your account by yourself. I believe your best bet is to submit a request here: https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us.
I'm not sure if they can actually help you but it should be your best option.